# Target WooCommerce product category archive pages from a child category term

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have a question regarding the product category. I have a category like that:

```
-electronic
-- laptop
-- mobile
```

then I want to create a logic for all product under `electronic`, I use `is_product_category( ‘electronic’ )`, but it doesn't work for electronic, it only works when URL is `mywebsite.com/product-category/electronic` when I use `mywebsite.com/product-category/electronic/mobile/` it doesn't work. Should I use the following codes or there is another option:

```
is_product_category( ‘laptop’ )
is_product_category( ‘mobile’ )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `term_is_ancestor_of()` to check if the current term (product category) being viewed belongs to a parent term.

I've written a simple helper function:

```
/**
 * @param int|object $parent ID or object term object to check.
 * @return bool Whether the product category being viewed is a child of the given parent category.
 */
function wpse_is_child_product_category( $parent ) {
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return term_is_ancestor_of( $parent, get_queried_object(), 'product_category' );
}
```

Usage:

```
if ( is_product_category( 5 ) || wpse_is_child_product_category( 5 ) ) {
    // . . .
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom conditional function that handle also any children product category on product category archives like *(handle term name, term slug or term id)*:

```
/**
 * Determines whether the query is for an existing product category archive page or for an ancestors product category archive page.
 *
 * @param int|string term ID, term slug or term name to check.
 * @return bool
 */
function is_maybe_child_product_category( $category ){
    if( is_product_category( $category ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    $object = get_queried_object();

    if( ! is_a( $object, 'WP_Term') ) {
        return false;
    }

    $taxonomy = $object->taxonomy;
    $children = get_term_children( $object->term_id, $taxonomy );
    $result   = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );

    if( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return in_array( reset($result), $children );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE:**

```
if ( is_maybe_child_product_category( 'laptop' ) ) {
    // Do something
}
```